# TypeError: 'DiscreteFactor' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch, bayesian-networks, pgmpy

I have a Bayesian algorithm program to be executed, I am using python 3

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pgmpy.models import BayesianModel
from pgmpy.estimators import MaximumLikelihoodEstimator
from pgmpy.inference import VariableElimination


heartDisease = pd.read_csv('heart.csv')
heartDisease = heartDisease.replace('?',np.nan)

print('Few examples from the dataset are given below')
print(heartDisease.head())

model = BayesianModel([('age','trestbps'),('age','fbs'),('sex','trestbps'),('exang','trestbps'),('trestbps','heartdisease'),('fbs','heartdisease'),('heartdisease','restecg'),('heartdisease','thalach'),('heartdisease','chol')])

print('\nLearning CPD using Maximum likelihood estimators')
model.fit(heartDisease,estimator=MaximumLikelihoodEstimator)

print('\n Inferencing with Bayesian Network:')
HeartDisease_infer = VariableElimination(model)

print('\n 1. Probability of HeartDisease given Age=28')
q=HeartDisease_infer.query(variables=['heartdisease'],evidence={'age':28})
print(q['heartdisease'])

print('\n 2. Probability of HeartDisease given cholesterol=100')
q=HeartDisease_infer.query(variables=['heartdisease'],evidence={'chol':100})
print(q['heartdisease'])
```

the error that i have recieved when i run my Bayesian network program is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-84a6b48627b2> in <module>
     23 print('\n 1. Probability of HeartDisease given Age=28')
     24 q=HeartDisease_infer.query(variables=['heartdisease'],evidence={'age':28})
---> 25 print(q['heartdisease'])
     26 
     27 print('\n 2. Probability of HeartDisease given cholesterol=100')

TypeError: 'DiscreteFactor' object is not subscriptable
```

So far I haven't seen this exact error here on stackoverflow. Can anyone explain why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying to solve the error I came up with the solution.

```
print('\n 1. Probability of HeartDisease given Age=28')
q=HeartDisease_infer.query(variables=['heartdisease'],evidence={'age':28})
print(q['heartdisease'])
```

```
print(q['heartdisesase']
```

over in this part of the code snippet **I just removed ['heartdisease'].**
here the output was actually trying to store itself into a array object, however the output actually is in special table format that cant be stored into an array so printing the actual answer 'q' gives you a required result.

```
print(q)
```

this get's your job done..!!

Answer (score 1):

The API you are using to fetch the data might be old . You should get back to the old API by simply passing joint=False as an another argument on line number 24. As in

```
24 q=HeartDisease_infer.query(variables=['heartdisease'],evidence={'age':28},joint=False)
25 print(q['heartdisease'])
print(prob_offer['Offer'])
```

Comment: sorry to say but i've tried doing that and it's not working i still get that error..